# jquery ajax on ubuntu 12.04 - does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and firefox.

I have this ajax query.

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'ajax_test',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(responseData) { 
                    alert('test');
                    alert(responseData.x + " " + responseData.y);
                    seriesJsonData[0]['data'].push({y: responseData.y, x: responseData.x});
                    graph.update();
              }
            });
```

I also see that from firebug that I get a status code of 200 and the expected json return.  Issue is that I cant evenb pop up a alert.  Not event for:

```
alert('test');
```

Is there a know issue for ajax and firefox un ubuntu?

Comment: Unless you have confirmed this to work in other operating systems or other browsers, please consider removing the `ubuntu` `firefox` and `ubuntu-12.04`. If you have and it worked, please be _explicit_ about it.

Comment: I workes on remote servers but no on dev server

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the clientside. The type of the server that serves your HTML/JS has nothing to do with it executing or not - it just serves the same code. As it currently stands, unless you try to be more specific - I doubt we'll be able to help you.